# How to edit my code so as to return true when the input word is a substring of an array value?

Tags: php

In the following example, the result is `FOUND`.

I want however to make 1 change to this, to echo `found` when the `$string = 'welc to my city'`
that means that if the string contains some of the letters of a word found in the array.

```
$string = 'welcome to my city';
$array = array("welcome","sunny");
if(0 < count(array_intersect(explode(' ', strtolower($string)), $array))) {
  echo 'found';
}
```

**Examples**

```
welcome to my city // true
welc to my city //true
welcomelkjdfs to my city //true
hi how are you // false
is it sunny? // true
what a big bright sun //true
```

Comment: take a look on preg_match

Comment: you need to better define what would and would not match

Comment: @nogad following your advice, I have updated my code. thank you

Comment: This looks like it might just be an exercise in learning. But in reality, it is not something you would really want to do. If you added the word `tomorrow` or `today` to `$array` then `to` from your string would match those words partially and return a bad true. You open yourself up to a whole bunch of false positives. If any word in your `$array` had an `a` in it, that would be true for the last string `what a big bright sun` because the word `a` exists somewhere partially in array.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn yes i see your point, any chance of having this with possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say about one change. But here is solution in one line

```
if(0 < count(
        array_filter(
            array_map(function ($value) use ($array) {
                foreach ($array as $word) {
                    if (strpos($word, $value) !== false || strpos($value, $word) !== false) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }, explode(' ', $string)))
    )
) {
    echo 'found';
};
```